# how to use TextEditingController from Autocomplete widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, autocomplete, widget, stepper

I need to use `TexteditingController` of the widget "autocomplete".
is to use the clear function when a stepper changes stage

[image: interface image]

I need to do that since if I go back a stage the text entered previously remains
this is the autocomplete code:

```
Autocomplete<Profesional>(
                     
                      optionsViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                          AutocompleteOnSelected<Profesional> onSelected,
                          Iterable<Profesional> options) {
                        return Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          child: Material(
                            elevation: 4.0,
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: 200.0,
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                itemCount: options.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  final Profesional option =
                                      options.elementAt(index);
                                  return GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      onSelected(option);
                                    },
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      title: Text(option.cod),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue query) {
                        return viewModel.efectores.where((efector) {
                          return efector.cod
                                  .toLowerCase()
                                  .contains(query.text.toLowerCase()) ||
                              efector.nombre
                                  .toLowerCase()
                                  .contains(query.text.toLowerCase());
                        });
                      },
                      fieldViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                          TextEditingController textEditingController,
                          FocusNode focusNode,
                          VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted) {
                        return TextFormField(
                          controller: textEditingController,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Seleccione Efector',
                          ),
                          autofocus: true,
                          focusNode: focusNode,
                          onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
                            onFieldSubmitted();
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      displayStringForOption: (efector) {
                        return efector.cod + ' - ' + efector.nombre;
                      },
                      onSelected: (efector) {
                        
                        viewModel.efector = efector;
                      }),
```

Answer (score 22):

You can use `RawAutocomplete` instead of `Autocomplete`.

In this case, you can pass your own `TextEditingController` and `FocusNode`. Then use the `TextEditingController` clear method to clear text if when needed.

If you need to clear the autocomplete view from the parent widget user global key.

See sample code here:

```
class CustomAutocomplete extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  final GlobalKey _autocompleteKey = GlobalKey();

  final List<String> _options = <String>[
    'aardvark',
    'bobcat',
    'chameleon',
  ];

  CustomAutocomplete({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  void clear() {
    _textEditingController.clear();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawAutocomplete<String>(
      key: _autocompleteKey,
      focusNode: _focusNode,
      textEditingController: _textEditingController,
      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
        return _options.where((String option) {
          return option.contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
        }).toList();
      },
      optionsViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
          AutocompleteOnSelected<String> onSelected, Iterable<String> options) {
        return Material(
          elevation: 4.0,
          child: ListView(
            children: options
                .map((String option) => GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        onSelected(option);
                      },
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(option),
                      ),
                    ))
                .toList(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all. 
It helped me a lot. Gracias!